# Toolbar back arrow with icon

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view, android-toolbar

How to display icon with back arrow in android toolbar like WhatsApp ?
I would like to reduce the space between the photo and the back arrow.
How can I reduce space?
I have:

- **ChatActivity.java**: the layout (which has only one view) is replaced with ChatFragment.java. Moreover, the toolbar is replaced here with fragment_chat_toolbar.xml
- **ChatFragment.java**: here the inputs, the emojis, the files etc. are managed

Thanks.

[My toolbar chat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yvv4q.png)

**fragment_chat.xml**

```
<LinearLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/layout_chat"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/fragment_chat_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/incoming_message"
        android:baselineAligned="false">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:paddingStart="2dp"
            android:paddingEnd="4dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_view_emoji"
                android:layout_width="28dp"
                android:layout_height="28dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:contentDescription="@string/emoji_button"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_emoji"
                android:tint="@color/total_black" />

            <com.vanniktech.emoji.EmojiEditText
                android:id="@+id/message_box_emoji"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/incomingColor"
                android:hint="@string/send_message"
                app:emojiSize="26sp"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_view_camera"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:contentDescription="@string/camera_button"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_camera"
                android:tint="@color/total_black" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/float_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_voice_recorder"
        android:tint="@color/white"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        app:fabSize="mini"/>
</LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

**fragment_chat_toolbar.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:clipChildren="false" >

<com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
    android:id="@+id/profile_photo"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    fresco:failureImage="@drawable/default_profile"
    fresco:placeholderImage="@drawable/default_profile"
    fresco:roundAsCircle="true" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chat_title_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chat_subtitle_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Did you edit your Manifest? Show some code as well

Comment: @moocow I edit the post

Comment: Did you add `android.parentActivityName` in Manifest?

Comment: yes: android:name=".home.chat.ChatActivity" android:parentActivityName=".home.MainActivity"

Answer (score 0):

Make Custom Toolbar as you like. Change your layout in RelativeLayout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llLeft"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:background="@drawable/transparent_layout_background"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivLeft"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_menu" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/llLeft"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/llRight"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/llLeft"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/llRight"
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
                android:lines="1"
                android:text="asdf"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llRight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/transparent_layout_background"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivRight"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_search" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Not work. I always have space between the photo and the back arrow.